# Reforming a path link with an absolute path

Tags: shell, command-line

On my Linux machine:

```
$ pwd
/usr/share/file/sharedspace

$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 system system 18 Aug 26 18:07 file.txt -> ../../original

$ rm file.txt
```

How would I reform this path link using an absolute pathname?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `readlink` command, with the `-f` flag to resolve the full path:

```
$ pwd
/usr/share/file/sharedspace

$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 25 12:25 file.txt -> ../../original

$ readlink -f file.txt 
/usr/share/original
```

From `man readlink`:

```
       -f, --canonicalize
              canonicalize by following every symlink in every  component  of
              the given name recursively; all but the last component must ex‐
              ist
```

Comment: Does this still work if the file has been removed?

Comment: Try it. Yes, it is work.

Comment: @deus_170 not with the `-f`, but without the `-f` it does work, yes. Try `ln -s /some/path/that/has/never/existed foo` and then `readlink foo`. The only drawback is that if this is a link to a link (`link1 -> link2 -> real_file`) then without the `-f` you will only get to `link2` and not `real_file`.